# XSL for each element get element value by attribute value

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath, xslt-1.0

I have following XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<STEP-ProductInformation ExportTime="2016-08-08 18:21:16" ExportContext="en-EN" ContextID="en-EN" WorkspaceID="Main" UseContextLocale="false">
<Classifications>
...
</Classifications>
   <Products>
      <Product ID="prd_119481004" UserTypeID="obj_product" ParentID="prd_eng_10000807">
         <Name>product name1</Name>
         <ClassificationReference ClassificationID="cls_0121781" Type="ref_etc_online_catalog"/>
         <Values>
            <Value AttributeID="atr_web_preoder_sell_type" ID="117184">23</Value>
            <Value AttributeID="atr_self_checkout_weight">0.13</Value>
            <Value AttributeID="atr_picking_weight_deviation">10</Value>
            <Value AttributeID="atr_renewable_goods_quantity">1000</Value>
            <Value AttributeID="atr_ext_var_gtin">atr_renewable_goods_quantity</Value>
            <Value AttributeID="atr_ext_bas_volume">90</Value>
            <Value AttributeID="atr_ext_var_uom_bas">ST</Value>
            <Value AttributeID="atr_space_planning_height">9,5</Value>
            <Value AttributeID="atr_space_planning_width">6</Value>
            <Value AttributeID="atr_ext_ar_gr_nr_1">6454100</Value>
            <MultiValue AttributeID="atr_ru_storage_temperature1">
               <Value>25</Value>
            </MultiValue>
            <Value AttributeID="atr_space_planning_depth">3</Value>
            <Value AttributeID="atr_ext_var_list_max_until">2017-09-08</Value>
            <Value AttributeID="atr_ru_vat" Derived="true">18</Value>
            <Value AttributeID="atr_pt_calc" Derived="true">fgsdg</Value>
            <Value AttributeID="atr_ru_shelf_life_val_uom" Derived="true">3</Value>
            <Value AttributeID="atr_shelf_num" Derived="true">3</Value>
            <Value AttributeID="atr_storage_num" Derived="false">280035555</Value>
            <Value AttributeID="atr_ru_bas_volume" Derived="true">0.09</Value>
            <Value AttributeID="atr_bypass_order" Derived="true">1017</Value>
            <Value AttributeID="atr_ru_shelflife_temperature1_formula" Derived="true">25°C</Value>
            <Value AttributeID="atr_picking_zone" Derived="true">1017</Value>
         </Values>
      </Product>
      <Product ID="prd_119478004" UserTypeID="obj_product" ParentID="prd_eng_10000807">
         <Name>product name2</Name>
         <ClassificationReference ClassificationID="cls_0121781" Type="ref_etc_online_catalog"/>
         <Values>
            <Value AttributeID="atr_web_preoder_sell_type" ID="117184">123</Value>
            <Value AttributeID="atr_self_checkout_weight">0.14</Value>
            <Value AttributeID="atr_picking_weight_deviation">10</Value>
            <Value AttributeID="atr_ext_var_gtin">4607177761992</Value>
            <Value AttributeID="atr_ext_bas_volume">90</Value>
            <Value AttributeID="atr_ext_var_uom_bas">ST</Value>
            <Value AttributeID="atr_space_planning_height">9,5</Value>
            <Value AttributeID="atr_space_planning_width">6</Value>
            <Value AttributeID="atr_ext_ar_gr_nr_1">6454100</Value>
            <MultiValue AttributeID="atr_ru_storage_temperature1">
               <Value>+25</Value>
            </MultiValue>
            <Value AttributeID="atr_space_planning_depth">3</Value>
            <Value AttributeID="atr_ext_var_list_max_until">2015-12-31</Value>
            <Value AttributeID="atr_ru_vat" Derived="true">18</Value>
            <Value AttributeID="atr_pt_calc" Derived="true">dgheyareatgraehgh</Value>
            <Value AttributeID="atr_ru_shelf_life_val_uom" Derived="true">3</Value>
            <Value AttributeID="atr_shelf_num" Derived="true">3</Value>
            <Value AttributeID="atr_storage_num" Derived="true">28003</Value>
            <Value AttributeID="atr_ru_bas_volume" Derived="true">0.09</Value>
            <Value AttributeID="atr_bypass_order" Derived="true">1017</Value>
            <Value AttributeID="atr_ru_shelflife_temperature1_formula" Derived="true">25 °C</Value>
            <Value AttributeID="atr_picking_zone" Derived="true">1017</Value>
         </Values>
      </Product>
   </Products>
</STEP-ProductInformation>
```

and rule If date in attribute 'atr_ext_var_list_max_until' <= current date than:

- ‘atr_storage_num’ must be empty
- ‘atr_shelf_num’ must be empty
- ‘atr_renewable_goods_quantity’ set to 0

My XSL transformation (without rule 'atr_ext_var_list_max_until' <= current date):

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:java="http://xml.apache.org/xslt/java" exclude-result-prefixes="java" version="1.0">

    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>


    <xsl:variable name="currdate" select="java:format(java:java.text.SimpleDateFormat.new('yyyy-MM-dd'), java:java.util.Date.new())" /> 
    <xsl:variable name="date" select="/STEP-ProductInformation/Products/Product/Values/Value[@AttributeID = 'atr_ext_var_list_max_until']" />
    <xsl:variable name="bool" select="$date = $currdate" /> 


    <xsl:template match="node()[@AttributeID = 'atr_storage_num']">
            <xsl:variable name="vAttribs" select="@AttributeID | @Derived"/>
            <xsl:variable name="date" select="/STEP-ProductInformation/Products/Product/Values/Value[@AttributeID = 'atr_ext_var_list_max_until']" />
            <Value><xsl:copy-of select="$vAttribs"/><xsl:text>CONST1</xsl:text><xsl:comment><xsl:value-of select="$date" /></xsl:comment></Value>
    </xsl:template>


    <xsl:template match="node()[@AttributeID = 'atr_shelf_num']">       
            <xsl:variable name="vAttribs" select="@AttributeID | @Derived"/>
            <Value><xsl:copy-of select="$vAttribs"/><xsl:text>CONST2</xsl:text></Value>     
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="node()[@AttributeID = 'atr_renewable_goods_quantity']">
            <xsl:variable name="vAttribs" select="@AttributeID | @Derived"/>
            <Value><xsl:copy-of select="$vAttribs"/><xsl:text>CONST3</xsl:text></Value>         
    </xsl:template> 

</xsl:stylesheet>

<!-- <xsl:comment><xsl:value-of select="$bool" /></xsl:comment> -->
```

doesn't work.
After using this XSL i get:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<STEP-ProductInformation ExportTime="2016-08-08 18:21:16" ExportContext="en-EN" ContextID="en-EN" WorkspaceID="Main" UseContextLocale="false">
    <Classifications>
    ...
    </Classifications>
       <Products>
          <Product ID="prd_119481004" UserTypeID="obj_product" ParentID="prd_eng_10000807">
             <Name>product name1</Name>
            ...
                <Value AttributeID="atr_renewable_goods_quantity">CONST3</Value>
                <Value AttributeID="atr_ext_var_list_max_until">2017-09-08</Value>              
                <Value AttributeID="atr_shelf_num" Derived="true">CONST2</Value>
                <Value AttributeID="atr_storage_num" Derived="false">CONST1<!--2017-09-08--></Value>
            ...
             </Values>
          </Product>
          <Product ID="prd_119478004" UserTypeID="obj_product" ParentID="prd_eng_10000807">
             <Name>product name2</Name>             
            ...
                <Value AttributeID="atr_ext_var_list_max_until">2015-12-31</Value>             
                <Value AttributeID="atr_shelf_num" Derived="true">CONST2</Value>
                <Value AttributeID="atr_storage_num" Derived="true">CONST1<!--2017-09-08--></Value>
            ...
             </Values>
          </Product>
       </Products>
    </STEP-ProductInformation>
```

For debugging i use `<comment>` and get in second context of result is value from first context of source.
Who knows how i must change my XSL transformation to get right context values:
in first of source `<Value AttributeID="atr_ext_var_list_max_until">2017-09-08</Value>` to first of result `<Value AttributeID="atr_storage_num" Derived="false">CONST1<!--2017-09-08--></Value>` and `<Value AttributeID="atr_ext_var_list_max_until">2015-12-31</Value>` to `<Value AttributeID="atr_storage_num" Derived="true">CONST1<!--2015-12-31--></Value>`, not value from first context of source 2017-09-08
?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming I'm understanding your question correctly and you are simply concerned about the CONST1 date, you need to change

```
<xsl:variable name="date" select="/STEP-ProductInformation/Products/Product/Values/Value[@AttributeID = 'atr_ext_var_list_max_until']" />
```

to

```
<xsl:variable name="date" select="../Value[@AttributeID = 'atr_ext_var_list_max_until']" />
```

Your current XSL will look for a node from the root that matches that path. The ".." means start searching from the parent of the current node you are looking at.

Comment: Thank You! It works fine. But now can't calling java function to reverse string. I am declaring `<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:java="http://xml.apache.org/xslt/java" xmlns:StringBuffer="java.lang.StringBuffer" exclude-result-prefixes="java" version="1.0">` and calling this function `<xsl:variable name="con1" select="StringBuffer:new(reverse($con))"/>`, but getting error " Cannot find external method 'new' (must be public)" How to call `reverse` correctly?

Comment: If this answer worked for your original question, please accept it. For your new question, I think the format for calling StringBuffer should be more like StringBuffer:reverse(StringBuffer:new($con)) but I have not tested it. I would recommend raising a new question so that someone who knows for sure can help.